# Counting zero-values when joining in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, null

I've got a few different SQL tables that I need to perform some counts on. This is for my job, so obviously the data is confidential, but I'll try to abstract it to something analogous. Imagine a University registrar's office...

Our first table contains a list of all courses that students have completed.

Table: `student_courses`

```
student_id | course_id
----------------------
123456     | MATH101
123456     | MATH203
785426     | PHYS305
  ...      |   ...
```

We also have tables for the different departments at our University, listing (among other things) the course ID and the year level of the course:

Table: `math_courses`

```
course_id | year
--------------------
MATH101   |  1
MATH201   |  2
MATH202   |  2
CALC103   |  1
STAT402   |  4
 ...      |  ...
```

Imagine similar `science_courses` and `general_courses` tables. The university has other departments, but we are only considering these three for now.

What we're looking for is a count of how many students have reached each combination of year/department.

For instance, if a student has taken both MATH101 and MATH201, their "year" for the math department will be considered "2".

Not all students have completed courses in all departments, and not all students have necessarily taken any courses in these three departments.

Basically, I'm looking to produce the following table:

```
max_math_year | max_science_year | max_general_year | student_count
---------------------------------------------------------------------
NULL          | NULL             | NULL             | 39847
NULL          | NULL             | 1                | 172
NULL          | NULL             | 2                | 0
 ...          |  ...             |  ...             |  ...
4             | 4                | 4                | 4986
```

I've built a temporary table to store the maximum level for each student, and it seemed to work properly, so for sake of this exercise, assume we have the following table:

Table: `#student_maximums`

```
student_id | max_math_year | max_science_year | max_general_year
----------------------------------------------------------------
123465     | 2             | NULL             | 1
782514     | 3             | 1                | NULL
874252     | NULL          | NULL             | NULL
 ...       |  ...          |  ...             |  ...
```

I want to return `0` when a row has no students who fit a certain combination, but if I run a count on the above table, it won't return zero-values.

Most of the time I'd do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to include the zeroes, but in this case, we're counting against data originally from four different tables. I've considered using a `CROSS JOIN` but that won't include `NULL` values in the rows, which I also need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on both suggestions, I came up with the following. I performed the join on the coalesced values, so that the null rows would actually line up across the tables.

Note, I was able to insert rows into the courses tables. If I wasn't, I'd UNION the zero value rows in the query.

```
INSERT INTO math_courses (0, NULL)
INSERT INTO science_courses (0, NULL)
INSERT INTO general_courses (0, NULL)

SELECT
    COALESCE(m.max_math_year, 0)
  , COALESCE(s.max_science_year, 0)
  , COALESCE(g.max_general_year, 0)
  , COUNT(DISTINCT student_id)
FROM
    math_courses m
CROSS JOIN
    science_courses s
CROSS JOIN
    general_courses g
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    student_maximums sm
  ON COALESCE(sm.max_math_year, 0) = COALESCE(m.year, 0)
  AND COALESCE(sm.max_science_year, 0) = COALESCE(s.year, 0)
  AND COALESCE(sm.max_general_year, 0) = COALESCE(g.year, 0)
GROUP BY
    COALESCE(m.max_math_year, 0)
  , COALESCE(s.max_science_year, 0)
  , COALESCE(g.max_general_year, 0)
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(m.max_math_year, 0)
  , COALESCE(s.max_science_year, 0)
  , COALESCE(g.max_general_year, 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not shure if i understood correctly, but is this what you want?

```
select
   coalesce(max_math_year, 0)
  ,coalesce(max_science_year, 0)
  ,coalesce(max_general_year, 0)
  ,count(*)
from #student_maximums
group by 
   coalesce(max_math_year, 0)
  ,coalesce(max_science_year, 0)
  ,coalesce(max_general_year, 0)
```

Comment: ...or maybe not. Looking again at the results, this does not provide the rows where the count is zero. E.g. if there are no students with math year 1, science year 2 and general year 2, then I want that row to appear in the results with a zero or NULL count.

Comment: Ok, now for something totally different :-) It's not (only) replacing NULL with 0, it's returning non-existent data. There are two ways to solve it: LEFT JOIN to a table/result set with all possible variations or (easier) add a dummy row for each possible variation into #student_maximums with a student 0 and NULLs for the other columns. Finally change the count to COUNT(NULLIF(student_id,0))

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need (though I'm not absolutely certain - if it isnt explain what is wrong):

```
UPDATE #student_maximums SET max_math_year = 0 WHERE max_math_year is NULL
UPDATE #student_maximums SET max_science_year = 0 WHERE max_science_year is NULL
UPDATE #student_maximums SET max_general_year = 0 WHERE max_general_year is NULL

SELECT max_math_year, max_science_year, max_general_year, count(*) as student_count
FROM #student_maximums
GROUP BY max_math_year, max_science_year, max_general_year
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: This provides the same results as dnoeth's answer, so I'll vote it up, but again, I'm missing rows where the count is zero.